# SQLLite SQL statement to find first non-zero of multiple columns

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have 2 rows in a table. Each row contains a primary key, and 5 additional columns, whose value may be 1, or 0.

So for example one of the columns is "TermsAccepted" and another is "CopyrightAcknowledged"

Row 1's "Terms Accepted" might be 0 or 1, and row 2's "Terms Accepted" might be 0 or 1 as well.

I'd like to know if at least one of the rows contains a 1 for each column. Do I have to use 5 subqueries to do this (I'd like to just have one row returned that tells me if any of the columns have 1's in them). It doesn't matter to me how many had 1, just so long as at least one column did.

Hopefully that made sense. How could I write a query to do this? I'm using SQL Lite. I'm somewhat stuck. Thanks so much!

Note: I can just return both records, and then use Swift (the programming language i'm doing this in) to just parse each column in each row and look for a 0 or a 1, but I was hoping for something in SQL to make it more elegant if possible.

Comment: Have you ever tried MySQL's NULLIF? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

Comment: hmm no I haven't, and didn't think of this - looking now.. unless you have an idea in mind of a query

Comment: Have a look here, if I understand correctly, it should fit your needs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282957/get-the-minimum-non-zero-value-across-multiple-columns

Comment: ah man i'm using sqlite which doesn't seem to have this. there is a min function, but not sure if that's what I need. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work but if anyone could confirm that would be great, thanks!

```
SELECT 
        max(TermsAccepted), 
        max(CopyrightAcknowledged), 
        max(LoggedIn), 
        max(LockedOut), 
        max(AccountCopied)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer until you have confirmed it actually solves your problem.

Comment: This solves my problem. I'll mark it answered when i'm allowed.